# Php function names paired with classes

Tags: php, function

Is it considered bad practice to pair function names with classes?

For example in kohana I could do the following.

```
function Model($a,$b){
    return new Model($a,$b);
}
```

Then I could drop all references to new, wouldn't have to make a $temp variable, and no factory clutter.

```
$temp = new Model('book');
$book=$temp->where('title','=','name')->find();
```

Or

```
$book = Model::factory('book')->where('title','=','name');
```

To

```
$book = Model('book')->where('title','=','name');
```

I understand global pollution is bad and it is slightly obscure to read at first, but it has it's benefits.

I mean it would be even more confusing if someone else defined a function that had no relation to the class, so why not use the function?

For example:

```
$book = new Model('book');
// looks so close to the above, it's scary
$book = Model('book');
```

Other Pros or Cons?

Comment: Seems like you don't like the PHP language so you're trying to work round it. You're missing an excellent opportunity to use that motivation to learn another language!

Comment: Try write three ugly names to safe four characters and confuse the heck out of people writing the code ("What's that function doing in addition to `new`?")? Edit @Joe: Last time I checked, `new` for class instanciaton was required for quite a few languages. There are many things one can critisize about the design of PHP, but this isn't one of the significant ones.

Comment: I wasn't criticising PHP on the new syntax. Just generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do that occasionally. It sometimes can make code a bit more readable.

It's called factory procedures. But it makes most sense if they are less shallow. For example if depending on parameters such a method might return different objects (alternative placeholder/stub objects):

```
class User { ... }

function User($id) {
    return ($id < 0) ? new PlaceholderUser() : new User($id);
}   // or another *stub object* to support the application flow
```

But of course you can just use that for nicer looks. It's basically a cleaner approach than the commonplace static factory methods. But I would reserve such wrapper functions for objects which you really use a lot. It makes no sense to fill up the function scope with a wrapper call for each existing class.

And the common criticism here is: inexperienced developers can easily get confused by the object instantiation without `new`. (Not sure if that's true. But that's often said in this context.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how constructors work prior to PHP v5 (i.e., instead of naming them "__construct") so you probably don't want to do that.

(Edit: Misunderstood your question, disregard. I didn't catch that the function was being defined in the global scope.)

Comment: thanks I'm pretty new to php (last year or so) so that is still interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a misfeature in PHP! I think an identifier should be truly unique in its namespace and should not differentiate between it being a class or a function. The same goes for PHP's (arbitrary?) distinction between properties and methods. (Ever tried calling a closure stored as a property on an object? )

Maybe someone can shed some light upon these peculiarities, they don't seem to have any merit to me, except to allow for ugly hacks.

I would strongly discourage from using such techniques. I have never yet seen a PHP book (or the official reference) mention this "collision" of identifiers explicitly. (Correct me if I'm wrong), but I think it's not commonly known. As already noted by mario, I would argue that this is confusing and misleading.

I would expect the `Model()` function actually do something, and I'd be annoyed to go to its definition only to find out, that someone was too lazy to use `new` and a variable!

Comment: Yeah I had noticed it has failed to be mentioned anywhere.  I haven't seen it mentioned on php.net or here on stack overflow anywhere.  I'm assuming when classes were introduced, they wanted to avoid any prior name collisions with functions so made them in a separate namespaces.  It is even funnier that 'namespaces' with the funny backslashes \ also pollute a separate namespace.  You can have functions, classes and now namespaces all with the same name.  :). Great for hacking around.