# Identical function and class names in PHP

Tags: php, class, function

Are there any circumstances where identically named classes and functions in PHP, could collide or cause problems in any way? For example:

```
function Foobar(){
    // ...
}

class Foobar{
    // ...
}
```

Cursory testing shows that PHP can discern between them based on context.

Comment: aren't functions usually named after what they do and classes are usually named after things/concepts?

Comment: @Gordon - Of course, I just wanted to provide a pseudo static `__invoke`.

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/04/15-top-php-coding-tutorials-tips-and.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they never collide. But:

### Do not do it.

You will confuse everyone if you do so, because I would not expect there to be a function and a class of the same name. Many don't even know it's legal to do so.

When I see an upper case name In PHP (first letter), I assume it is a class. If you put () around it, *I* will know it's a function. But I wouldn't assume that there is a class of the same name. All you do is confuse people. Some might assume: "Cool, I didn't know you could omit `new`". I don't know what your intents are, but if it's to get rid of the `new` keyword - and only that - it's very bad. I will assume you do *more* than just that, and will go check what that function actually does, and I'll get angry if I find out it does nothing except returning a new instance without doing anything... I just wasted my time looking up a function that does... *nothing*.

Comment: Thanks @phant0m - Care to elaborate?

Comment: regarding edit; Understandably so; my intent was to provide a sort of static version of `__invoke()`, to maintain brevity in view generation, where less is more; and not always to skip `new`

Comment: While it *does* return an instance of the identically named object, it creates a sort of object collection with it. Rather than create a static method in the class, I figured to reduce coupling I could benefit from such a function, because there are still circumstances under which I would want to create `new` objects from that class. I could just as easily name the function `getNew___()` but I figured the association between identical names would be seemingly implicit, not so much confusing.

Comment: In that case, create a (static) factory method that **tells** the user that you do something special, and what if possible.

Comment: Of course; this was merely an option that passed by and I figured I'd leave it to SO to show me the light :)

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Ah I see. I hope you found it :)

Comment: Making opinions bold or fat headlines doesn't make them more valid. - And the confusion part here is most assuredly constrained to newcomers. Factory methods don't require the stale 08/15 scheme just to be understandable; that's flimsy.

Comment: @mario: I can relate to that, but I believe that this is generally considered bad practice and not merely my opinion (I hope). What did you mean in the last part? I don't think I said anything regarding 08/15-factories (isn't that a german idiom btw?) What I meant is: A factory whose only purpose is returning a new instance, does not deserve its own factory method.

Comment: @mario & @phant0m - I'm merely trying to balance the load between comprehensible brevity, and effective communication of design. While I still believe there are circumstances under which my proposed practice could be optimal, perhaps this specific instance is not. I was more interested in the technical limitations of such a choice anyways. Also, unfamiliar with the **08/15** mention, what's the reference?

Comment: @TomcatExodus: 08/15 is a german idiom that means "vanilla"-something, or "run-of-the-mill". [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442232/php-function-names-paired-with-classes/6442995#6442995) is mario's take on this issue just a few days ago. While he's correct that it's concise and very pleasant to use, it's just not clear what it does when someone else comes along. Why not name it `UserFactory()`/`user_factory()` instead? I just think it should say something about the nature of the factory, so you realize there's more going on than just `return new ...`

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/04/15-top-php-coding-tutorials-tips-and.html

Comment: @Jagedeesan: How is this link relevant?